# When is $G$ isomorphic to $G \times G$?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a *finitely generated* nontrivial group $G$ such that $G \cong G \times G$?

Here are some properties which such a group $G$ has to satisfy:

- $G$ is not abelian (otherwise $G$ is a noetherian $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and the composition of the first projection $G \times G \to G$ with an isomorphism $G \cong G \times G$ will be bijective, i.e. $G$ is trivial).
- $G$ is perfect (apply the first observation to $G/G'$)

Comment: apart from the trivial group, I guess.

Comment: $G$ must also not be residually finite (as a finitely generated residually finite group is Hopfian, i.e. has no isomorphic proper quotients).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes.  Some Googling turns up [J. M. Tyrer Jones, "Direct products and the Hopf property," *J. Austral. Math. Soc.* **17** (1974), 174-196](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=4894728).

Comment: Thanks! I used google, but didn't know to feed it properly ;).

Comment: has anyone else the problem, that the link to the pdf doesn't work?

Comment: @Henrik: hmm.  The paper might not be freely available.  I found it indirectly: it was referenced in a paper of Baumslag and Miller (http://rio.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/caissny.org/Publications/some%20odd%20finitely%20presented%20groups.PDF) which I found on Google, and which may have a more general construction in it.

Comment: It's available for free: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=4894728&fulltextType=RA&fileId=S144678870001675X

Answer (score 16):

As a geometric group theorist, one would of course relax the question by allowing passage to finite index subgroup, i.e. one would ask for groups such that G and GxG have finite index subgroups, which are isomorphic. One then calls G an GxG commensurable, and for this weaker property there are a lot of interesting examples. My favourite one right now is the Grigorchuk group. But even commensurability to GxG is a very restrictive property: It implies, for instance, that if G is infinite, then it has infinite asymptotic dimension. I just stumbled over this result in the thesis of J. Smith. The proof is almost trivial: Since G is coarsely equivalent to GxG, it is coarsely equivalent to G^n for all n. Now Z embeds 
quasi-isometrically into G (since G is infinite), and hence Z^n embeds coarsely into G^n (hence G), so asdim G is at least asdim Z^n for all n, and we conclude. This is in particular the case if G and GxG are isomorphic. The upshot is, that for a group of finite asymptotic dimension one cannot have G=GxG, not even up to finite index.