# Can a simply connected manifold satisfy $\simeq \times $?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a simply connected, (finite dimensional) smooth manifold. Is it possible that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $M\times M,$ without $M$ being contractible? This would imply $\pi_n(M)\times\pi_n(M)\cong \pi_n(M)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ I know there are groups which satisfy $G\times G\cong G,$ but this is a very strong condition, and this condition still seems much weaker than the condition in question.

According to [When is $G$ isomorphic to $G \times G$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43805/when-is-g-isomorphic-to-g-times-g), if even one nontrivial homotopy group is finitely generated, this is impossible.

(I asked this on stackexchange and didn't get any responses.)

Comment: You should include a link to your identical thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739282/can-a-simply-connected-manifold-satisfy-m-cong-m-times-m

Comment: I put a sketch answer in the comments to your original thread.  The basic idea is to use the Kunneth theorem and apply it to your homotopy-equivalence to ask what the cup-length is for your manifold.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Dave Benson](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451401/can-a-simply-connected-manifold-satisfy-simeq-%c3%97#comment1167394_451420) for pointing out an algebra error in the first draft of this answer and a missing detail.

Suppose $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite dimensional, simply-connected, and noncontractible CW complex. Then for $k=\mathbb Q$ or $k = \mathbb Z/p$ for some $p$, there exists an $i>0$ such that $H_i(M; k)$ is nontrivial, otherwise $X$ would be contractible by the homology Whitehead theorem  (see Corollary 3A.7 of [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)).

The Künneth theorem implies $H_{2i}(M \times M;k)$ is nontrivial which implies $M$ can't be homotopy equivalent to $M \times M$.

The simply-connectedness assumption is necessary since the homology could potentially vanish in all degrees.

Comment: So is there a counterexample in the non-simply-connected case?

Comment: @Zerox If there is, it must be a space with contractible universal cover. The question is then equivalent to: is there a group $G$ which acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $G\cong G\times G?$

Comment: I suppose you're using the fact that if $A$ is a non-zero abelian group then either $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A$ or $\mathop{\rm Tor}(\mathbb{Z}/p,A)$ for some $p$ must be non-zero.

Comment: @DaveBenson I am using that the tensor product of nontrivial vector spaces is nontrivial.

Comment: You also need that some $H_i(M;k)$ is non-zero.

Comment: @DaveBenson Right, this is a consequence of the Homology whitehead theorem and the SES $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \oplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p\rightarrow 0$

Comment: I don't think there is any such sequence.

Comment: Bear in mind that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has the property that its tensor product with the additive group of any field is zero.

Comment: @DaveBenson Sorry, the quotient is $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ where $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty = \mathrm{colim} (\mathbb{Z}/p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^3 \rightarrow \dots)$. A reference for the homological fact is  Corollary 3A.7 of Hatcher.

Comment: Exactly what I was saying. You're using the fact that if $A\ne 0$ then either $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A \ne 0$ or $\mathop{\rm Tor}(\mathbb{Z}/p,A)\ne 0$. This is the proof given in Hatcher.

Comment: @DaveBenson I agree; I mentioned this SES because one can also prove it using that e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508832/homology-with-integral-coefficients-vs-homology-with-field-coefficients/3508920#3508920). But I guess it is not trivial to deduce such a fact, so it might be helpful if I had included it with my answer.

Comment: Situation resolved! G'night.

Answer (score 25):

Lemma. If $A$ is an abelian group satisfying $A\otimes A=0$ and $\mathop{\rm Tor}(A,A)=0$ then $A=0$.

Proof. Since $\mathop{\rm Tor}$ is left exact on abelian groups, an inclusion of a finite cyclic group $C$ in $A$ gives an injection $\mathop{\rm Tor}(C,C)\to \mathop{\rm Tor}(A,A)$. So if $\mathop{\rm Tor}(A,A)=0$ then $A$ is torsion free. Then $A$ embeds in $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A$, so if $A\otimes A=0$ then $(\mathbb{Q}\otimes A)\otimes(\mathbb{Q}\otimes A)=\mathbb{Q}\otimes(A\otimes A)=0$. So $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A=0$ and then $A=0$.

Now given your manifold $M$, since it is smooth, simply connected, and finite dimensional, it has the homotopy type of a finite dimensional CW complex. So by the Whitehead theorem, if it's not contractible then it has some non-vanishing homology group in degree $\geqslant 2$. Let $H_k(M)\ne 0$ with $k\geqslant 2$ as large as possible (so $k$ is at most the dimension of $M$). Then by the Künneth theorem and the lemma, either $H_{2k}(M\times M)\ne 0$ or $H_{2k+1}(M\times M)\ne 0$. So we have a contradiction if $M\times M\simeq M$.

Comment: The lemma must be in a book somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: Probably the same book where this problem is a homework problem.  :)

Comment: @DaveBenson This is a nice answer, thank you.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thanks for your initial comment. If you do find this problem in a textbook I would be interested in knowing which one.

Comment: @JoshLackman: I have not looked in an algebraic topology textbook in some time.  That said, I think you've found yourself a pretty textbook problem, if you were to write one.